# List of List- delete characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have a huge list like

```
list = [["a", "bfgf", "c%2"], ["b", "hhj", "kkkk", "f%2"]]
```

I want to remove %2 end of every  last item in lists of list.

I tried

```
list = [[item[-1].replace('%2', '') for item in lst] for lst in list]
```

and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way does not work because you are not changing the ***value in place***. Your statement simply takes ***a copy*** of every sub-list, stores it in `lst`, then changes the data ***in that copy***, and ***not the actual list*** itself.

Try it in this way, and tell me if it works.

```
myList= [["a","bfgf","c%2"],["b","hhj","kkkk","f%2"]]

for i in range(len(myList)):
    Last=myList[i].pop()
    Last=Last.replace("%2","")
    myList[i].append(Last)

print (myList)
```

Comment: I am a beginner in coding so I am confused about some part. How can I introduce sublist lenght in this loop?

Comment: @Susu I just changed the code in my answer. Take a look at it. I had a small typo ('SubList' should've been myList). My bad! Anyways, take a look at this code, and see if you can understand it. If not, I'll explain. Also, run it somewhere and provide different lists to check.

Comment: @Susu If you understood the statements in the loop, you can combine all of them 3 statements into 1 as `myList[i].append(myList[i].pop().replace("%2",""))`

Comment: @Susu Please mark either of the 2 answers as correct.

Answer (score 1):

For your nested list you can also use a nested list comprehension to remove the unwanted characters.

```
ini_list = [["a", "bfgf", "c%2"],["b", "hhj", "kkkk", "f%2"]]
ini_list = [[val.replace('%2', '') for val in sublist] for sublist in ini_list]
print(ini_list)
# output
[['a', 'bfgf', 'c'], ['b', 'hhj', 'kkkk', 'f']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help